Infinite chessboard coloring without tetris pieces
Suppose we have an infinitely large chessboard, and we recolor the squares using black and white colors. Now we want to color as many black squares as we can, without forming any tetris pieces. Which means that the black squares we colored have connected components only of size $1,2$ or $3$.
(Here any square only has 4 adjacent squares in direction up, down, left and right. A connected component only allow black squares connected in the given 4 directions)
So what is the highest possible density for such a coloring?
To make the question more clear.
Assume in a finite $n\times n$ board, we can color at most $a_n$ many black squares. Then what is the limit of $a_n/n^2$ when $n\to\infty$?
If we only allow components of size $\le 1$ or $\le 2$, then any $2\times 2$ subboard could only contain $2$ black squares. So in the two cases, $a_n=\lceil n^2/2\rceil$ then $a_n/n^2\to 1/2$. But for our question, we can have a periodic $5\times 5$ coloring as follows:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\blacksquare & \blacksquare & \square & \blacksquare & \square \\
\blacksquare & \square & \blacksquare & \blacksquare & \square \\
\square & \blacksquare & \square & \square & \blacksquare \\
\blacksquare & \blacksquare & \square & \blacksquare & \square \\
\square & \square & \blacksquare & \square & \blacksquare \\
\end{matrix}
$$
So by this construction we have $a_n/n^2\ge13/25>1/2$ for sufficiently large $n$.

I get 19/36 from [    1     1     0     1     1     0;
1     0     1     0     1     0;
0     1     0     1     0     1;
1     0     1     0     1     0;
1     1     0     1     1     0;
0     0     1     0     0     1];

@Empy2 I believe you can delete the 4th row from your commented construction and improve to $16/30$.

The best (non-periodic) packing for a $3\times 4$ coloring is $\begin{matrix}#&#&.&#\#&.&#&#\.&#&.&.\end{matrix}$. So the answer must be somwhere between $16/30$ and $7/12$

Ran some code, and found out the best (non-periodic) packing for a $8 \times 100$ coloring has $444$ black tiles, shifting our upper bound from $\approx 0.583$ to $0.555$. Also checking for patterns on this packing, it strongly seems to suggest that limit of $a_{8\times n} / 8n$ is $62/(8\cdot 14) \approx 0.5536$. Will try to run some experiments on lower bound next

@EnEm I think the boundary condition is highly nontrivial in this problem in finite cases and it has a big impact on the optimal solution. I don’t know what your algorithm is. My guess is that 30-by-30 should give a much better bound than 9-by-100 because the boundary is smaller in this case.

@ZTransformer Thats tough with my algo. It uses dynamic programming with states as column number and previous column configuration, which has time complexity $\mathcal{O}(5.08^{n} n^2 m)$. I think an algo using ILP might be efficient enough to get it, but I am not well versed with that.
